# Pass selected text as argument to a script and replace selected text with output from the script

Tags: replace, shell-command

I'd like to pass some selected text in a buffer to a python script. The python script will process the string and print the result to stdout. This output should replace the original string that was selected. Can this be done?

To tackle this, I first pass a selected buffer to my python script. Below is the elisp function that I wrote, following a similar function to implement the command `wc`

```lisp
(defun it ()
  (interactive)
  (shell-command (concat "echo "
                         (buffer-substring (mark) (point))
                         " | /Users/john/bin/t ")))
```

This command succeeds and prints the output in the mini-buffer. Is there an elisp-way to overwrite the selected text with this output?

Comment: Just a comment, for a full buffer you can just use `(buffer-string)`, but I understand the current code is more suitable for what you finally intend to do.

I think it is nicer if you format the code in different lines b.t.w., I edit you question and do it for you

Comment: Would `shell-command-on-region`, bound to `M-|` fit your requirements?

Comment: rsp's comment provides a better answer than my answer below. I was not aware of `shell-command-on-region`. I guess it would be handy to put it in an answer instead of a comment...

Comment: ok, I added the comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would `shell-command-on-region`, using a prefix argument fit your requirements? `shell-command-on-region` is by default bound to `M-|` (Meta key with '|' key) and the prefix argument is by default bound to `C-u` (Control 'u').

Combining those you can use the key sequence `C-u M-|` (Control 'u' followed by Meta '|') to pipe a region of text to a command and replace the region with the output of the command.

It asks for the command to pipe the selected text to, in your example that would be `/Users/john/bin/t`, and runs that command with the selected text on standard input.

Comment: Please consider showing some code, to illustrate what you suggest.

Comment: My suggestion is to use the `shell-command-on-region` command to fulfil the OP's goal (instead of trying to fix the elisp function listed).

Comment: @rsp can you explain how to use a prefix argument when executing `shell-command-on-region`? Also, what does binding to `C-u M-|` mean?

Comment: @linuxfan, updated the answer with some more explanation.

Answer (score 2):

This is perfectly possible and you are almost there.
For example to replace e.g. the command/selected text `ls` in a buffer you can use:

```lisp
(defun replace-region-from-shell-output ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((command-output (shell-command-to-string (buffer-substring (mark) (point)))))
    (kill-region (mark) (point))
    (insert command-output)))
```

Comment: rsp's comment provides a better answer. I was not aware of `shell-command-on-region`